# Discounting Future Cash Flows

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been having some trouble discounting cash flows of an account in a specific state, using R's dplyr package.

For my example we will assume the data set of one account is as follow:

```
+--------+--------+-------+-----------+--+
| PERIOD | STAGE  | RATE  | CASH FLOW |  |
+--------+--------+-------+-----------+--+
|      1 | Open   | 10%   |       100 |  |
|      2 | Open   | 10.5% |       120 |  |
|      3 | Open   | 10%   |        50 |  |
|      4 | Open   | 11%   |        40 |  |
|      5 | Closed | 10%   |         0 |  |
|      6 | Closed | 11%   |         0 |  |
|      7 | Open   | 11%   |        30 |  |
|      8 | Open   | 10%   |        40 |  |
|      9 | Open   | 10.2% |        50 |  |
+--------+--------+-------+-----------+--+
```

The account is in the "Open" Stage during period 1-4 and 7-9.

I would like to calculate the discounted future cash flows, using the dplyr package in R, at each observation date using the rate applicable to the specific period.

The desired result should be as follow:

```
| PERIOD | STAGE  | RATE  | CASH FLOW | PV of Cash Flows  |
|--------|--------|-------|-----------|-------------------|
|      1 | Open   | 10%   |       100 | 279.3797 (1)      |
|      2 | Open   | 10.5% |       120 | 198.5124 (2)      |
|      3 | Open   | 10%   |        50 | 86.036 (3)        |
|      4 | Open   | 11%   |        40 | 40                |
|      5 | Closed | 10%   |         0 | NA                |
|      6 | Closed | 11%   |         0 | NA                |
|      7 | Open   | 11%   |        30 | 107.6109 (4)      |
|      8 | Open   | 10%   |        40 | 85,37205 (5)      |
|      9 | Open   | 10.2% |        50 | 50                |
```

Where:

(1) = 100 + 120 /(1.105) + 50 /{(1.1)(1.105)} + 40 /{(1.11)(1.1)(1.105)}

(2) = 120 + 50 /(1.1) + 40 /{(1.11)(1.1)}

(3) = 50 + 40 /(1.11)

(4) = 30 + 40 /(1.1) + 50 /{(1.102)(1.1)}

(5) = 40 + 50 / (1.102)

Is it possible to achieve the desired result using dplyr syntax ?

Some additional issues relating to the problem:

- The code solution must be generic, i.e different accounts may have different structures
- The data set that I'm using is relative big (therefore) I would like to avoid loops (if possible).
- Each "Open" Stage is independent of the next stage as shown in the illustrative example. In other words, the cash flows from period 7 - 9 will not be considered for 1st "Open" stage during period 1-4.

I would appreciate any advice / example code.

Thanks in advance !

---

Update:

Data structure:

```
structure(list(Period = 1:9, Stage = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Close", "Open"), class = "factor"), 
    Rate = c(0.1, 0.105, 0.1, 0.11, 0.1, 0.11, 0.11, 0.1, 0.102
    ), Cash_flow = c(100, 120, 50, 40, 0, 0, 30, 40, 50)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: What have you tried? Could you share the data also in a reproducible format using `dput()`?

Comment: I've added the data structure in the original post. At the moment I do not have a clue how to approach this without using loops to discount the cash flows for the remaining observations using the rate and cash flow at each of those future time periods.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `dplyr` mixed with a tiny bit of `data.table`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  arrange(-Period) %>%
  group_by(stage_nr = data.table::rleid(Stage)) %>% 
  mutate(pv_cf = Cash_flow + cumsum(lag(Cash_flow, default = 0) / (1 + lag(Rate, default = 0)))) %>%
  arrange(Period)

  Period Stage  Rate Cash_flow PV_cf stage_nr pv_cf
   <int> <fct> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>    <int> <dbl>
1      1 Open  0.1         100 290.         3 290. 
2      2 Open  0.105       120 201.         3 201. 
3      3 Open  0.1          50  86.0        3  86.0
4      4 Open  0.11         40  40          3  40  
5      5 Close 0.1           0   0          2   0  
6      6 Close 0.11          0   0          2   0  
7      7 Open  0.11         30 112.         1 112. 
8      8 Open  0.1          40  85.4        1  85.4
9      9 Open  0.102        50  50          1  50
```